# RecyclerView Items are not refreshing

Tags: java, android

The thing is that when I add the data that I entered using the AlertDialog and the data can be added to the database, however the recyclerview did not refresh. But I have added the notifyDataSetChanged and it still doesn't work. I don't have much experience in coding. I hope you could help me out! Thank you so much. Following is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_address);

    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    fab = findViewById(R.id.addressfab);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.manageAddressRV);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    mAddressList = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapterAddress  = new AdapterAddress(mAddressList, ManageAddress.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterAddress);

    getAddress();

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addAddress();
        }
    });
}

private void getAddress(){
    fStore.collection("Users").document(userId).collection("Address").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            mAddressList.clear();

            for (int i=0; i<queryDocumentSnapshots.size();i++){
                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(i);

                if(documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                    String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                    String address = documentSnapshot.getString("Address");

                    Address  addresses = new Address (id, address);

                    mAddressList.add(addresses);
                }
            }

            mAdapterAddress.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
}


private void addAddress(){
    AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.address_input_layout, null);
    myDialog.setView(myView);

    final  AlertDialog dialog = myDialog.create();
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    final EditText userAddress = myView.findViewById(R.id.userAddress);

    final Button cancel = myView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    final  Button save = myView.findViewById(R.id.save);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String UserAddress = userAddress.getText().toString();

            if(UserAddress.isEmpty()){
                userAddress.setError("Address is Required");
                userAddress.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            else {
                Map<String, Object> AddAddress = new HashMap<>();

                AddAddress.put("Address",userAddress.getText().toString());

                fStore.collection("Users").document(userId).collection("Address")
                        .add(AddAddress)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                Toast.makeText(ManageAddress.this,"Address has been added successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            }
                        });
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Because you are not calling `getAddress ()` when the save button of dialog is pressed.

Comment: In the `onSuccess` callback, you should build & add the `Address` object & then add it via the `mAddressList.add(addresses);`.